# Trying to set the prompt colour in .bashrc file but it won't work when logged in as root

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set the prompt colours in the `.bashrc` file and it works as long as I'm not logged in as root. If I try to use the command `sudo su` and then see if the bash prompt turns red, it doesn't. However when I run `source .bashrc` it works just fine. Maybe this would work if I try to edit the .bashrc file for the root user, but I'd rather not do that. This is the script I've written.

```
bold=$(tput bold);
reset=$(tput sgr0);
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then
    PS1="${bold}\e[38;2;171;178;191m[\e[m";
    PS1+="${bold}\e[38;2;97;175;239m\u\e[m";
    PS1+="${bold}\e[38;2;152;195;121m@\e[m";
    PS1+="${bold}\e[38;2;198;120;221m\h:\e[m";
    PS1+="${bold}\e[38;2;86;182;194m\W\e[m";
    PS1+="${bold}\e[38;2;171;178;191m]\e[m";
    PS1+="${bold}\e[38;2;229;192;123m$ \e[m";
    PS1+="${reset}";

else
    PS1="${bold}\e[38;2;224;108;117m[\u@\h \W]# \e[m";
    PS+="${reset}";
fi
```

I have attempted to add a second if statement instead of the else, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2025

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, but this is about OS config. Please ask on [unix.se] instead.

Comment: Usually `root` have its own home directory (and, thus, its own `.bashrc` file) When you run `source .bashrc` you are using `.bashrc` in the current directory, not in the home of the current user.